# Where did "**dates**" buffer come from?

Tags: org-mode

I was working away in emacs using org-mode to register some task I was doing, when I noticed a new buffer had appeared called "**dates**".  It had a number of dates presented in it such as "ISO date", "Gregorian", "Number of days until the end of the year", etc.  Where did that come from?

Alas I had left it too late to use `C-h l` to see what key combination brought it up.  Searching within emacs help system and google is proving futile....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, `grep` gives a single answer:

```el
(defun org-agenda-convert-date ()
  (interactive)
  (org-agenda-check-type t 'agenda)
  (let ((day (get-text-property (min (1- (point-max)) (point)) 'day))
        date s)
    (unless day
      (user-error "Don't know which date to convert"))
    (setq date (calendar-gregorian-from-absolute day))
    (setq s (concat
             "Gregorian:  " (calendar-date-string date) "\n"
             "ISO:        " (calendar-iso-date-string date) "\n"
             "Day of Yr:  " (calendar-day-of-year-string date) "\n"
             "Julian:     " (calendar-julian-date-string date) "\n"
             "Astron. JD: " (calendar-astro-date-string date)
             " (Julian date number at noon UTC)\n"
             "Hebrew:     " (calendar-hebrew-date-string date) " (until sunset)\n"
             "Islamic:    " (calendar-islamic-date-string date) " (until sunset)\n"
             "French:     " (calendar-french-date-string date) "\n"
             "Bahá’í:     " (calendar-bahai-date-string date) " (until sunset)\n"
             "Mayan:      " (calendar-mayan-date-string date) "\n"
             "Coptic:     " (calendar-coptic-date-string date) "\n"
             "Ethiopic:   " (calendar-ethiopic-date-string date) "\n"
             "Persian:    " (calendar-persian-date-string date) "\n"
             "Chinese:    " (calendar-chinese-date-string date) "\n"))
    (with-output-to-temp-buffer "*Dates*"
      (princ s))
    (org-fit-window-to-buffer (get-buffer-window "*Dates*"))))
```

Comment: That could be it, though I am still unsure how I got there.  HeHe "Gregorian" not "Jordan"...

Comment: From Agenda Mode buffer (`C-c a a` for example) the letter `C` calls it up.  Mystery solved.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Press `C` from Agenda buffer.

> C runs the command org-agenda-convert-date (found in
> org-agenda-mode-map), which is an interactive byte-compiled Lisp
> function in ‘org-agenda.el’.
>
> It is bound to C,   <Calendar/Diary> .
>
> (org-agenda-convert-date)

Dixit Emacs help

Comment: Thanks for summary, but that is the Answer given above already.

Comment: As I see it, the difference is the medium (Lisp vs English). I thought it might be useful to have an explanation in English.  Shall I delete my answer?